# Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, hibernate, tiles

I'm trying to run my web application using Spring, Hibernate and Apache Tiles.
It seems the code has no errors, but I'm just getting a 404 page.

/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Servlet 'dispatcher' configured successfully
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/example/index.html]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /index.html
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/index.html]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/index.html] are [/**]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/index.html] are {}
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/index.html] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@32645ccb] and 1 interceptor
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/example/index.html] is: -1
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

context:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <value>
            /WEB-INF/**/tiles.xml
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.controller" />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<default-servlet-handler />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.example.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Before adding all the hibernate stuff I tried the web app and it worked just great. But what's a webapp without a database?

I already spent hours on this and just can't find the problem...

**UPDATE**

Controller:

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class BlogController {
    @RequestMapping("/index.html")
    public String posts(Map<String, Object> map) {
        return "posts";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this request (index.html) supposed to go through a controller?  or is it just a static HTML file?  I see 'Did not find handler method' so if you are trying to use a controller - spring cannot find it

Comment: In `web.xml`, I see mapping to `/`, do you probably mean `/*`? What URL are you trying to reach?

Comment: Can we see your controller too - the whole thing?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved it.

There are two contexts: root (application wide) and servlet context
I defined `viewResolver`, `tilesConfigurer`, `tx:annotation-driven` and `mvc:annotation-driven` in the root context.

Moving it to the servlet context solved the problem.

**UPDATED**
I've moved `viewResolver`, `tilesConfigurer`, `tx:annotation-driven` and `mvc:annotation-driven` definitions from `applicationContext.xml` to `contextConfigLocation` (`dispatcher-servlet.xml`)

Comment: Could you elaborate ? I've also served time in there.

Comment: Hey, I am facing same issue. Could you please elaborate more or sample code also works !

Comment: Sorry, thats long time ago. Check your context configuration. I just moved the mentioned elements.

Comment: This definitely needs to be more elaborated

Answer (score 0):

Try sending ModelAndView instead of String 
Or

You can send map object as parameter to ModelandView method(which is already overloaded)

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/") 
public class BlogController {
    @RequestMapping("/index.html")
    public ModelAndView posts(Map<String, Object> map) {
      return new ModelAndView("/index.jsp", "status", status);
    } 
}
```